# How can I get Apple Mail to pick the correct From: address?

Tags: macos, email, gmail

I own a mid-2010 MacBook Pro running Lion (I know -- but don't want to upgrade!)  When I am responding to an email, just below the 'Subject' line there is a field called 'From' followed by two separate drop down boxes.  The first comes up automatically with the correct email I am using for that particular gmail account, but as of about a month ago, the second box comes up with my husband's gmail address rather than mine.  I have to manually change it (or else responses go to my husband).  If I delay in sending my email (for which I've manually changed the second box) I can literally watch it default back to my husband's email address.  It is maddening!

Don't know if this is related or not, but at about the same time, I began having problems with my gmail accounts being listed as 'offline' even though I'm able to send and receive messages.

Any help welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The box below the Subject line is called the Mail Box.

It is like the Post office name.

It is used to select from which email account you want to send it.

The first box is From, the second is the Account from which to be send.

You can change it here:

[image: mailbox]

When you open new email window you ca also change the settings here:

For the From field, and choose which account to use.

[image: send mail]